# Ubuntu 16.04 is not detecting my Nvidia 820M graphic card, how should I install the drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04  is not detecting my Nvidia 820M graphic card, how should I install the drivers ?

Will I face any problems if I install the drivers?

Comment: Do you have Nvidia Optimus? If so, you're in for lots of pain.

Comment: I had the same problem. When you install/reinstall Ubuntu make sure to click the third party graphics option. Once installed update according to http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html.

Answer (score 1):

You say "does not detect" but you probably mean "does not install and configure proprietary drivers". I suppose it might not detect the hardware at all, but that unlikely. Run "lspci", for example, to check.

If you need the nvidia drivers, your question was answered here:

[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

After installation of nvidia-364, don't worry about Optimus and getting automatic mode switching. Stay away from Bumblebee or other magic. That's a chore for advanced users, and perhaps not even them. Be content with running "nvidia-settings" where you can choose to use the nvidia or built-in Intel display, if your computer has both. Then you have to restart and you are stuck with that video card for whole session.

On my system, the Intel is more stable, less likely to crash at random and never shows static or pixelated letters.  I have very poor performance of the Nvidia driver to external monitors. Now that X configuration is mostly automatic, it is also now mostly impossible to fix and adjust (old man talking).  Probably, my monitors are not fast enough to keep up with Nvidia. However, with Intel, there are other drawbacks. The cursor is invisible after suspend and you have to switch to VT1 and back to get it to show again. That's really annoying.

Comment: Thank you, it detected it in the terminal but in additional drivers it's not!

Comment: Should I install the driver or not?   I need to play games, will Intel be good?